# What is the subbasis of the topology of pointwise convergence?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I am trying to understand the above text.

> A subbase for the topology of pointwise convergence is of the form
> $\{f:f(x)\in G\}$, where $x\in X$ and $G$ is open $Y$.

Does this mean that a subbasis is all the functions where all their images are in $G$ or all the functions where at least one of their images belong in $G$?

Comment: It's the set $\{[x,G]\mid x \in X, G \subseteq Y \text{ open }\}$ and $[x,G] = \{f: X \to Y\mid f(x) \in G\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subset of $Y^X$ consists of all functions $f$ such that the value $f(x)$ belongs to the set $G.$

For example if you take $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ then the subbasis $\mathcal{B}$ of point - open topology in this case is $$\mathcal{B} =\{U_x^G : x\in\mathbb{R} , G\subset \mathbb{R} , G-\mbox{open}\}$$ where $$U_x^G =\{f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} : f(x)\in G\}.$$

Comment: When you say the value of $f(x)$ belongs in $G$, do you mean all the values of $f$?

Comment: The value at fixed point $x$

Comment: Yes so we pick all the functions that have at least one of their values in $G\subseteq Y$

Comment: No we pick a functions for wchich its value at fixed point $x$ belongs to $G.$ For example if you take $f(x) =x^2 $ then $f\in G_0^{(-1,1) }$ but the function $g(x) =x^2 +0.5$ does not belong to $G_0^{(-1,1)} $ however $g(0.5 ) \in (-1,1)$

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: It is written above. But there should by replaced $G_0^{(-1,1)}$ by $U_0^{(-1,1)}.$

Comment: What does $U_0^{(-1,1)}$ mean here?

Comment: It is written in my answer where the subbase of point-open topology is described. $$U_0^{(-1,1)} =\{ f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} : f(0)\in (-1,1) \}$$

Comment: but isn't $g(0)=0.5\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: So $g\in U_0^{(-1,1)}$.

Comment: Yes. I've made mistake. Try $g(x) =1-x^2$ then for some $x$ say $x=0.5 $ we have $g(0.5)=0.75 \in (-1,1) $ but $g\notin U^{(-1,1)}_0$ since $g(0)=1\notin (-1,1).$ that is the difference you asked for.